Adding leading zeros and reduce decimal place in Notepad++

Add leading zero for values to the 4th column. I need them to be exactly 5.
Also I need the 5th column to be a whole number with no decimals
And I need the 6th column to be 2 digits after the decimal.

"058300000228",1,1,"52238",1.0000,0.0000
"058300000228",100,1,"52238",1.0000,0.0000
"058300000228",1,0,"0218",200.0000,8.3400
"058300000228",100,0,"0218",200.0000,8.3400
"058300000229",1,1,"51952",1.0000,0.0000
"058300000229",400,1,"51952",1.0000,0.0000
"058300000229",1,0,"0227",400.0000,158.3600
"058300000229",400,0,"0227",400.0000,158.3600
"058300000230",1,1,"1450",84.0000,335.1600
"058300000230",14,1,"1450",84.0000,335.1600


Please, edit your question and add expected result. Explain also what you have tried and what didn't work. What to do when there is more than 5 digits in column 4 and if there is only 1 decimal in column 6? This can't be done in one pass, you'd better to write a script in your favorite scripting language. You can also easily do it in MS excel or LibreOffice Calc.

What's the question in the 1st place? This is not a homework website, you should ask precise questions that will help others instead of giving us tasks to do for you.

This is using Notepad++'s Macro recording function. It reads the multiple key sequences you want to repeat. Instructions:

Start at beginning of a line (press home key)
Tool bar -> select "Macro" -> Start recording
Press ctrl-{right-arrow} 7 times
Press 0 5 times
Press home key once
Press "down arrow" key once
Toolbar -> Macro -> "stop recording"

Play macro, press ctrl-shift-p

I think you didn't understand the question. Why do you add 5 zeros? This is not wanted. What about columns 5 and 6?
